# python getLogger not working on derived Logger

Tags: python, logging

I've created a CustomLogger which extends logging.Logger.  I'm trying to use getLogger to get my logger instantiation. Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import atexit

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self,name,logfile):
        super().__init__(name, level=logging.DEBUG)
        self.logfile_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
        self.logfile_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logfile_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s'))
        self.addHandler(self.logfile_handler)
        atexit.register(logging.shutdown)

        print("Created logger: " + name + "  " + logfile)

mycustom = CustomLogger("cust","./cust.log")
mycustom.critical("from direct write")  #CORRECTLY WRITES TO FILE
logging.getLogger("cust").critical("from getLogger") #FAILS TO WRITE TO FILE
```

How can I use getLogger to write to mycustom instantiation?

My intent is to use logging.getLogger("cust") in other modules to write to this logger.

Comment: Seems like you are misusing logger. You arent doing anything in the custom logger that you would need a custom logger for. All of this can be accomplished easily without overriding the logger or breaking out of the global logger pattern.

Comment: This is only a snippet of code. I have other special methods in CustomLogger. I just didn't copy and paste those.

Comment: What are those extra steps? Could be you rather have a custom filter or custom Stream which dont break the getLogger mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

`logging.getLogger("cust")` try to get or create with `logging.Manager`, `Manager` instance new logger with `Logger` class by default, you could change this globally by call `logging.setLoggerClass`. If you do not want this, you could register your logger instance to `Manager`:

```
class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self,name,logfile):
        super().__init__(name, level=logging.DEBUG)
        ...
        self.manager.loggerDict[name] = self
```

obviously, this is a hack.